# How change the colors for annotation?

Tags: annotation

I search how to change the colours of annotation en 2.8 Blender's version, because the « pencil » fort them don't appear.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

You can select the pencil on the tool panel (arrow) and you change the color using over on the object context menu (press N to pull up) under View.  I've circled where you can change the color.

[image: info]

Comment: I don't fin it... look : http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/29/djby.png

Comment: press "N" and the bar will pop up

Comment: Perfect ! I found it.